# tableView Cell Labels Stack When I Scroll

Tags: swift, scroll, label, tableview, cell

I have a custom tableView, entirely created in code. IE, the cells need to be in code too.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "inventoryCell", for: indexPath)


            let namelabel = UILabel()
            namelabel.frame = CGRect(x: 145, y: 10 , width: 200, height: 30 )
            namelabel.text = itemToShow.name
            namelabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
            namelabel.backgroundColor = .clear
            cell.addSubview(namelabel)

            let detailLabel = UILabel()
            detailLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 145, y: 50 , width: 200, height: 50 )
            detailLabel.text = itemToShow.detail
            detailLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
            cell.addSubview(detailLabel)

            let inventoryImage = UIImageView()
            inventoryImage.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 130, height: 130)
            inventoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "emptyInventorySlot")
            cell.addSubview(inventoryImage)

        
        
        return cell
    }
```

It works great, and you can see it loads perfectly. The top image is the load, the bottom image is once I scroll to the bottom. You can see the text labels seem to all stack on top of each other.

[image]

Comment: It's generally not recommended to add views in `cellForRowAt indexPath` because the cells are `recycled / reused` and therefore this method is called multiple times which will lead to views being laid on top of views added previously. You could `override prepareForReuse` in your custom cell implementation and clear of any views however consider adding the views to the `contentView` within your `custom UITableViewCell` and use `cellForRowAt indexPath` for configuring the data of that cell only.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend doing it this way.
It's better to move the code that creates namelabel, detailLabel and inventoryImage to an inventoryCell class derived from UITableViewCell.

But you can make it work.
Since table cells are reused and the reused cells already contain the created subviews, you need to either remove the subviews or treat cells with already created subviews differently.

And you should place your labels in the contentView of your UITableCellView.

To make your code work you can do this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "inventoryCell", for: indexPath)

        // remove any subviews from contentView from recycled cells 
        cell.contentView.subviews.forEach{ $0.removeFromSuperview() }

        let namelabel = UILabel()
        namelabel.frame = CGRect(x: 145, y: 10 , width: 200, height: 30 )
        namelabel.text = itemToShow.name
        namelabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        namelabel.backgroundColor = .clear
        // add any label to contentView of the cell
        cell.contentView.addSubview(namelabel)

        let detailLabel = UILabel()
        detailLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 145, y: 50 , width: 200, height: 50 )
        detailLabel.text = itemToShow.detail
        detailLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
        // add any label to contentView of the cell
        cell.contentView.addSubview(detailLabel)

        let inventoryImage = UIImageView()
        inventoryImage.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 130, height: 130)
        inventoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "emptyInventorySlot")
        // add any label to contentView of the cell
        cell.contentView.addSubview(inventoryImage)

    
    
    return cell
}
```

Better would be:

- create a UITableViewCell subclass
- place your label placement and configuration there
- take care of cell reuses, override prepareForReuse() to support cell reuse
- register this class as a table view cell for your tableView
- cast your dequeued cell to your UITableViewCell subclass

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to implement this after work today.